# Picker for numbers

Tags: android

ok so im making a lovely little app for my phone that will let me convert bases. This would make my APCS homework much better and provide me some practical and useful coding experience.

I see lots of questions concerning the time and date pickers but that is not what i am looking for. For example, on iOS, if you press on something that is almost like a dropdown menu you can scroll through the selections and choose which one you want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a [spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html)?

Comment: that will work nicely.... not to go read all of that API info and try and figure out how to use it...... Thanks!

Comment: The api page links to a tutorial which should have all the necessary details.